# Converting multilinestring and multipolygon to multipoint in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

In PostGIS I have 2 layers:'lines' (multilinestring, public, gid, geom) and 'polygons' (multipolygon, public, gid, geom). I try to find how to convert them to multipoint (or point). I suspect that ST_CollectionExtract (https://postgis.net/docs/ST_CollectionExtract.html) can do that, but I didn't find any sql example; I tried sth like:

```
SELECT ST_CollectionExtract (public.polygons as geom,1)
```

but it doesn't work.

I'm not good at SQL.  I usually try to find some sql example that uses all those things like gid, geom, table_name, column_name etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [ST_DumpPoints](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) which returns the a path (the indices of the point in the geometry) and a geometry. You can extract your points like so:

```
SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom 
FROM table
```

This returns rows with a point geometry in each one. (Here, the inner geom is the geometry column of your source table. The trailing `.geom` is the geometry member of the elements of the returned set: a point.)

The extra set of parentheses around the function call are necessary. `ST_DumpPoints(geom).geom` wouldn't work.